# How to get a particular sibling value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the value of the sibling with the class `i_search` when clicked.

```
<tr>                        
    <td>12</td>
    <td class="request">24</td>
    <td>36</td> 
    <td><a class="i_search" href="javascript:;" title="Detalle">btn</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>                        
    <td>6</td>
    <td class="request">12</td>
    <td>18</td> 
    <td><a class="i_search" href="javascript:;" title="Detalle">btn</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>                        
    <td>3</td>
    <td class="request">6</td>
    <td>9</td>  
    <td><a class="i_search" href="javascript:;" title="Detalle">btn</a></td>
</tr>
```

here my jQuery:

```
$(".i_search").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var numRos = $(this).find(".request:first").val();
});

console.log(numRos);
```

But it shows `null`

Comment: if every tr looks the same I would go for
var numRos = $(this).parent().parent().find("td").eq(1).text();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options, the first:

```
var numRos = $(this).closest('tr').find('.request').text();
```

Or:

```
var numRos = $(this).parent().siblings('.request').text();
```

`val()` is applicable only to interactive form elements, what you want is the text of a `<td>`, so `text()` should be used instead.

Getters, in jQuery, will return, in this case the text, of only the first element matched by the selector. In your case there is only the one, so it will work appropriately.

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jQuery.com/closest/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jQuery.com/find/).
- [`parent()`](http://api.jQuery.com/parent/).
- [`siblings()`](http://api.jQuery.com/siblings/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jQuery.com/text/).

Comment: `'this'`? That doesn't seem right. As well as `.te t()`

Comment: @cerbrus: you're right, I have no idea why - halfway through the answer - I decided to go wrong. Edited, and fixed...

Comment: Why, thank you! And seriously, composing (even simple code) on iPad is a recipe for frustration... Sigh.

Comment: I absolutely agree :-(

Comment: And, @Irvin, thank you for the rescue edit earlier :)

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need:

```js
$(".i_search").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var numRos = $(this).parents('tr').find('.request').html();
    alert(numRos);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>      
        <td>12</td>
        <td class="request">24</td>
        <td>36</td> 
        <td><a class="i_search" href="javascript:;" title="Detalle">btn</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>      
        <td>6</td>
        <td class="request">12</td>
        <td>18</td> 
        <td><a class="i_search" href="javascript:;" title="Detalle">btn</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>      
        <td>3</td>
        <td class="request">6</td>
        <td>9</td> 
        <td><a class="i_search" href="javascript:;" title="Detalle">btn</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `find` search a child of the element matching the selector, you have to traverse up the DOM and match its parent using closest then you can use find.

Try:

```
$(".i_search").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var numRos = $(this).closest("tr").find(".request").text();
    console.log(numRos);
});
```